# Why Maven folder Structure is not proper if i clone the project from GIT?

Tags: java, git, selenium, maven

I Have cloned the Maven project from GIT and using import in eclipse imported the project using Maven Existing project option. But Still its not showing Folder Structure as Expected. its Showing the packages directly not showing any src folders! How to overcome this issue?
[image]

Comment: It says the Pom.xml file has problems.  Fix them first.

Comment: When i run the pom.xml its showing this error - > 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM 
pom.xml /selenium-bdd-example-project line 8 Maven pom Loading Problem

Comment: Please show the pom file... apart from that it looks like you should add `<relativePath/>` in the parent definition of your pom file... Apart from that that is a WARNING... please check on plain command line via `mvn package` and show the errors...

Comment: Please link to the git repository so others can see what you can see.